# How to fix unsupported operand types in pyinputplus?

Tags: python

So I'm very new to coding and I'm following an online book tutorial from "Automate The Boring Stuff", I'm trying to replicate a program that adds up to ten, it works correctly if I input a single integer, but if i put in something like 55, or 3 7, it returns with:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

```py
import pyinputplus

def addsuptoten(num):
    numlist=list(num)
    for i, dig in enumerate(numlist):
        numlist[i]=int(dig)
        if sum(numlist) != 10:
            raise Exception('The digits must add to 10, not %s'%(sum(numlist)))
    return int(num)

response=pyinputplus.inputCustom(addsuptoten)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, people are likely to be more receptive to a question if you demonstrate what you've tried so far to solve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The input to the function is a list of strings. As you loop through it, you convert each element from a string into an integer, in-place. However, you evaluate `sum(numlist)` before you're finished the conversion. This will attempt to summate a list containing both integers and strings, which gives you that exception.

You should be able to solve that problem by converting the entire list before summing it up:

```py
def addsuptoten(num):
    numlist=list(num)
    for i, dig in enumerate(numlist):
        numlist[i]=int(dig)
    if sum(numlist) != 10:
        raise Exception('The digits must add to 10, not %s'%(sum(numlist)))
    return int(num)
```

(Although, I believe you have another problem on the return line).